# getting a pixel color from screen

Tags: c, linux, xlib

I'm trying to find out the color value of a specific pixel(which will be specified using screen coordinates(100,100) for example)
using xlib, this is a cli tool.

here's some code I have been trying out(no dice):

```
Display *display;
    display = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
    Window root = XDefaultRootWindow(display);
    XImage *image;
    image = XGetImage(display,root,0,0,1,1,AllPlanes,XYPixmap);
    printf("pixel:%lu\n",XGetPixel(image,0,0));
    XCloseDisplay(display);
```

it always prints 0 if I change tthe x,y value of XGetPixel  to a value other than 0

maybe I'm looking in the wrong place or using teh wrong functions

thanks

Comment: I've just tested it and it works for me. Could it be that your (0,0) pixel is a the border of toolbar or something and always black?

Comment: anything other than 0,0 always results in "0" :( ,  is that not the case for you?

Comment: No, for me it returns always the proper value. Can you show the code with the non-zero coordinates? Maybe you are putting your X,Y coordinates in the call to `XGetPixel()` instead of `XGetImage()`?

Comment: well, it turned out I forgot to change the width of the image after setting it initially to 1,1 
it's working now thank you

Answer (score 0):

I Forgot to change the width from 1,1
setting it properly fixes everyhting